# jquery iterating collection with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a post index page.

On clicking the a given post's show comment button, the comments of the post get visible. This is easy since I can use `this` then `find` based on the click location.

```
//open hidden post comments and replies in post thread
$(document).on('click', '.open-all-post-comments', function (event) {
  var post_id = $(this).data('pid');
  var all_replies = $('#post_' + post_id).find('.post-comment-replies:has(.post-comment-reply)');
  all_replies.show();
  $(this).closest('.open-all-post-comments-row').hide();
});
```

Now, on page load I'd like to make the the edit dropdown visible for the posts where the post author is the current user. I can't figure out how to go thru all the posts on the page, check if the given data attr equals the current user's id then and make the dropdown visible if so.

Here is the code I have at the moment. How should I change it to make it work?

```
//checking all posts on the page and show the dropdown if user is the post author

$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  if ($('.post-container').length > 0) {
    if ($('.edit-post-dropdown-button').data('postauthorid') == $('#bodycurrentuser').data('currentuserid')) {
      $('.edit-post-dropdown-button').removeClass('hidden');
    };
  };
});
```

_post partial (single post's html)

```
<div class="panel panel-default post-panel" id="post_<%= post.id %>">
  ........
  <li class="dropdown edit-post-dropdown-button hidden" data-postauthorid ="<%= post.user_id%>">
    ......
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `$` before `(document)`

Comment: as u_mulder said you should use `$.each` function to iterate through the posts.If you need a more detailed answer show your html so we can help you

Comment: George, updated with the html. This belongs to a single post. I guess this is enough, or should I share more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to iterate through each post.I could not test it but something like this should work:

```
$( '.post-panel' ).each(function( index ) { 
        if ($(this).find('.edit-post-dropdown-button').data('postauthorid') == $('#bodycurrentuser').data('currentuserid')) {
            $(this).find('.edit-post-dropdown-button').removeClass('hidden');
           }
});
```

Comment: Thx George, I pulled it off.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't even need to go trough all the post of the page, you need to select that item where `postauthorid` === `currentuserid`.

```
var currentUserId = $('#bodycurrentuser').data('currentuserid');
var $currentUserDropdowns = $('edit-post-dropdown-button[data-postauthorid=' + currentUserId + ']');

$.each($currentUserDropdowns, removeHiddenClass);

function removeHiddenClass() {
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Francesco, this one is not working, since there are more posts from the same user on the same page. Or did I miss something?

Comment: ok, then you are right, but it's easy to extend to more posts, I will update it for you

Comment: Thanks Francesco, can't wait to see it!

Comment: I guess there is a typo (extra pipe). Could you remove it for others who may see this post?

Comment: Pls also see my prev comment. Francesco, compared to George Pant's solution which one is the better/faster etc.?

Comment: in terms of performance they are equivalent, I would just directly the element instead to select his parent and then go to the child